# Which part of this is a non-negative integer? (factorial error)

Tags: matlab, octave, factorial

This is the script:

```
n=input('Enter the number of rows: ')
PT=zeros(n);
row=1;
col=1;
while row~=n+1
  for col=1:1:n
    PT(row, col)=(factorial(row-1)/(factorial(col-1)*factorial(row-col)));
  end 
  row=row+1;
  col=1;
end
PT
```

When I run it, it says to enter the number of rows, so I enter '4'. Then it says

```
error: factorial: all N must be real non-negative integers
error: called from
    factorial at line 40 column 5 
    hw6p2 at line 7 column 17
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to implement here? What formula?

Comment: Quoting from the help center, *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the* ***desired behavior***, ... *See: How to create a [MCVE]."*

Comment: You left out a part of the quote from the help center that says that this question is within guidelines.
Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem **or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**

Comment: @CameronAavik ***or*** is between specific problem and error. desired behavior is a ***must***

Comment: I interpreted the "or" as being between the three options, I have asked about this in SO Meta for further clarification https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357879/5701576

Answer (score 3):

In the line `for col=1:1:n`, `col` can get up to the value `n`, even when `row` is still `1`. Therefore when you call `factorial(row-col)`, `row` can be `1` and `col` can be `2`. This is where it can be negative.

Comment: This should be a comment IMO since this doesn't provide the solution of the problem. It only indicates the problem

Comment: The question was which part of their code causes the negative factorial. I think this answers that question.

Comment: Sometimes the answer can be even Yes/No but that doesn't make it an appropriate answer IMO

Comment: We can't know what the right solution is if we don't know what the intended outcome is. The other answer says to use abs, but this could also be fixed by changing it so that col only goes as high as row.

Comment: and that's why you should've commented that to ask what output he's expecting

Comment: Sorry if I'm being annoying, but I've changed 'col=1:1:n' to 'col=1:1:row', and when I try to run it, it says parse error in regards to the semicolon in line 7. I deleted that, and then it said parse error in regards to the 'end' corresponding to the for loop. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Megan start by providing what you're trying to implement here

Comment: @Sardar It's the Binomial Coefficients, or [Pascal's Trainagle](https://colalg.math.csusb.edu/~devel/IT/main/m12_binomial/src/s01_pascal.html) - see the yellow box near the bottom of the page.

Answer (score -2):

Your factorial input should not be negative .....in the loop (row-col) is taking a negative value and error popped. Use *abs* to make it positive always.

```
n=input('Enter the number of rows: ')
PT=zeros(n);
row=1;
col=1;
while row~=n+1
  for col=1:1:n
    PT(row, col)=(factorial(row-1)/(factorial(col-1)*factorial(abs(row-col))));
  end 
  row=row+1;
  col=1;
end
PT
```